# Regex to segregate list of strings and regexs

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I have python input list containing both strings and regexs.

```
str_regex = ['normal_string_1', ''^(?![_\-])[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+$', 'normal_string_2']
```

I need to segregate this list into list of strings and list of regexs. 
In summary below are input and required output.

Input :

```
['normal_string_1', ''^(?![_\-])[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+$', 'normal_string_2']
```

Output :

```
['normal_string_1', 'normal_string_2'], ['^(?![_\-])[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+$']
```

I am planning to form a regex to do this. Something like "Should contains only `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]`". Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Please post some example strings,expected output,attempts .

Comment: A regular expression within itself is a valid string. Please provide some samples (input, desired outputs, with any exceptions you might have).

Comment: `(say, str_regex)` is not a list but a tuple

Comment: examples would help greatly

Comment: Hi - I've edited your question to try to make it easier to understand and format better.  However, you need to give us the rules on what is a "*normal string*" for you.  You hint that it might be strings that contain only [a-zA-Z] - is that your specification?  This would mean regular string couldn't contain numbers, or spaces, or underscores.  You need to define what a normal string can contain and how it is distinguished from a regexp before we can help.  It may be impossible unless you have a very tight specification- because your "*normal strings*" are probably valid regexp, too...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to pass a string to a function along with a list of different regexes, returning the regex that matches. This should do the trick:

```
import re
def contains(string, regexes):
  lst = []
  for regex in regexes:
    match = re.findall(regex, string)
    if len(match) > 0 and len(match[0]) == len(string):
      return string + " contains only \"" + regex + "\""
  return "No matching regex was found"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  regexes = [
    "[a-z]+",     # lower case
    "[A-Z]+",     # upper case
    "[a-zA-Z]+",  # mixed case
    "\d+",        # digits
    "[a-z\d]+",   # digits and lower case
    "[A-Z\d]+",   # digits and upper case
    "[a-zA-Z\d]+" # digits and mixed case
  ]
  print contains("SHOULD" , regexes)
  print contains("should" , regexes)
  print contains("Should" , regexes)
  print contains("123"    , regexes)
  print contains("123as"  , regexes)
  print contains("123AS"  , regexes)
  print contains("123aS"  , regexes)
```

The above prints

```
SHOULD contains only "[A-Z]+"
should contains only "[a-z]+"
Should contains only "[a-zA-Z]+"
123 contains only "\d+"
123as contains only "[a-z\d]+"
123AS contains only "[A-Z\d]+"
123aS contains only "[a-zA-Z\d]+"
```

Comment: This is not what I wanted. May be its my bad that question was not formed correctly. Edited the question.